# Android encryption algorithms

Tags: android, encryption

I'm encrypting byte arrays and I'm wondering which cipher algorithms (AES, DES, MD5, etc) are available by default in Android 4.0.3 and up. I couldn't find any official reference guide.

Since I'm not particularly familiar with encryption in android I'm posting relevant code in which I'm interested in.

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] value, String cryptoPass) {
    try {
        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(cryptoPass.getBytes("UTF8"));
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        // Cipher is not thread safe
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        Log.d("bitmap", "Decrypted: " + value + " -> " + value);
        String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(value), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("bitmap", "Encrypted: " + value + " -> " + encryptedValue);

        return encryptedValue.getBytes("UTF-8");

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
};

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] value, String cryptoPass) {

    try {
        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(cryptoPass.getBytes("UTF8"));
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        byte[] encrypedPwdBytes = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
        // cipher is not thread safe
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        return (cipher.doFinal(encrypedPwdBytes));

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry if i was ambiguous, i edited the question.